# Storing all forms answers in one single file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to store every response from the forms submited by users in AppScript.
I am using this code, but I get the error:

```
'TypeError: id_form.getResponses is not a function'
```

My code:

```
//store answers in one file
```

EDIT:

```
function setDestination_responses(form) {
  var id_form = FormApp.openById(form.getId());
  var spreadsheet_responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TX4GOsihKuXFhbZMhtFWPYmGwrxii0XhyGhyTKzPKhc');

  var sheet_spreadsheet_responses = spreadsheet_responses.getSheets()[0];
  var titles = id_form.getItems().map(e => e.getTitle());
  var formResponses = id_form.getResponses();
  var values = formResponses.map(f => f.getItemResponses().reduce((o, i) => {
    var r = i.getResponse();
    return Object.assign(o, {[i.getItem().getTitle()]: Array.isArray(r) ? r.join(",") : r});
  }, {})).map(o => titles.map(t => o[t] || ""));

  if (values.length==0) {console.log(`VALUES EQUAL TO 0 ${values}`)} 
  else{sheet_spreadsheet_responses.getRange(sheet_spreadsheet_responses.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)};
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `form.getResponses()`.

Comment: Well, the script does not raise error now, but no answer is stored in my spreadsheet. Is there anythin I am missing?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. `console.log(formResopnses)`

Comment: you are trying to read from a form id, which is a string, whereas you should be reading from a `Form` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `getResponses()` returns FormResponse object. In your situation, I think that it is required to retrieve the response values using `getItemResponses()`.
- When `appendRow` is used in a loop, the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var id_form = FormApp.openById(form.getId());
  var spreadsheet_responses = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1X1rhvgTfFq0-SoecLcgDP1Zu8x93Vba0EKMTBkRFJcw');
  var sheet_spreadsheet_responses = spreadsheet_responses.getSheets()[0];
  var titles = id_form.getItems().map(e => e.getTitle());
  var formResponses = id_form.getResponses();
  var values = formResponses.map(f => f.getItemResponses().reduce((o, i) => {
    var r = i.getResponse();
    return Object.assign(o, {[i.getItem().getTitle()]: Array.isArray(r) ? r.join(",") : r});
  }, {})).map(o => titles.map(t => o[t] || ""));
  sheet_spreadsheet_responses.getRange(sheet_spreadsheet_responses.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When you run this script, all responses are retrieved from the Google Form and they are appended to the 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet.
- About `var id_form = FormApp.openById(form.getId());`, in your script, `form` might be the same with `FormApp.openById(form.getId())`.
- At Google Form, when the empty answer is submitted, the question has no value. By this, it is required to consider this. So at first, the titles are retrieved from the items, and the values are created using the item titles. I thought that this might be an important point.

#### References:

- [getResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponses())
- [getItemResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses())

Comment: thanks! very well explained!!

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Why am I getting this error? it is pointing to values.length. Is it because we need to pase the parameter "value" to the function?

Comment: @alb Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Why am I getting this error?`, in that case, I think that `values` might have no values. So for example, how about putting `if (values.length == 0) return;` before the line of `sheet_spreadsheet_responses.getRange(,,,)`? If you want to check it, you can do it by `console.log(values)`.

Comment: Ok! I edited the post with your suggestion, but nothing is written  off in the spreadshet when submitting responses. Still too newbie in JS, sorry

Comment: @alb Thank you for replying. About `I edited the post with your suggestion, but nothing is written off in the spreadsheet when submitting responses.`, in this case, I think that because `values` is empty. By `if (values.length == 0) return;`, the script is finished. When you checked `console.log(values)`, what result did you get? Unfortunately, I cannot know your Google Form. So I cannot clearly answer your current situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.