# How can I get the responses directly form a Google Form and send then to a new spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've been struggling to make a script that takes all the responses directly from a Google Form and sent it (or copy it) to a spreadsheet.  I also want to send the spreadsheet to Google Drive after the copy is created (I already manage to do this part)

When I run the script it doesn't show any errors. The spreadsheet is created and stored in the given drive folder but the sheet is empty.

The is the script:

```
function getItemResponses() {

// Open a form by ID and create a new spreadsheet.
var form = FormApp.openById('1ohh3SYGm0F1wzIGeQenk6Vt-epeXY2UHgdYXtH5knWA');


//Prepare new name
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
var name = form.getTitle() + " Copy " + formattedDate;

//Prepare file system objects
var oldfile = DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId());
destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1u6HQQUWXKIkpakInbS9u6opWK10T91Ez");

//create new spreadsheet
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);

//Copy to newSpreadSheet
var form = FormApp.openById('1ohh3SYGm0F1wzIGeQenk6Vt-epeXY2UHgdYXtH5knWA'),getItemResponses,newSpreadsheet


//move to destination folder
var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
var parents = newFile.getParents();
while (parents.hasNext()) {
    var parent = parents.next();
     parent.removeFile(newFile); //remove from default folder
}
destination.addFile(newFile);

}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve all response values from the existing Google Form.
- You want to put the retrieved values on the new Spreadsheet.
- You want to put the new Spreadsheet in the specific folder.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the new Spreadsheet is created. But the response values are not put. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.
- In order to retrieve all response values from Google Form, I thought that this sample script might be able to be used. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69537071/7108653)
- In order to move the created Spreadsheet to the specific folder, in this case, you can use `moveTo`.

When the above points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function getItemResponses() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1ohh3SYGm0F1wzIGeQenk6Vt-epeXY2UHgdYXtH5knWA');
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var name = form.getTitle() + " Copy " + formattedDate;
  destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1u6HQQUWXKIkpakInbS9u6opWK10T91Ez");
  
  // Create new Spreadsheet.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);

  // Move the created Spreadsheet to the specific folder.
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
  newFile.moveTo(destination);

  // Retrieve all response values from Google Form and put them to the created Spreadsheet.
  var sheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var titles = form.getItems().map(e => e.getTitle());
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var values = formResponses.map(f => f.getItemResponses().reduce((o, i) => {
    var r = i.getResponse();
    return Object.assign(o, {[i.getItem().getTitle()]: Array.isArray(r) ? r.join(",") : r});
  }, {})).map(o => titles.map(t => o[t] || ""));
  values.unshift(titles);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, a new Spreadsheet is created and it is moved to the specific folder, and all response values are retrieved from Google Form and they are put to the created Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [moveTo(destination) of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)
- Related thread.

  - [Storing all forms answers in one single file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69536568/7108653)

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike ! ,

Thanks you so much for your answer. Your scrip works awesome!
I'm very happy to see that what I want to do is actually possible.

Could it be possible to edit the scrip to add a time stamp (date + time) and the email of the person that sent the answer? 

And something else. The form I'm working with has 2 titles and when I use the script it brings this titles as column A and B on the spreadsheet. Could it be possible to skip those?

My apologies if I'm asking too much.
Thank you again for your answer! :-)