# How can I account for Google Forms questions that are not answered?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to iterate through a Google form and its responses to print them to a PDF in a way that works regardless of what the questions (items) are and which ones are answered or not.

The problem is that some types of items - e.g., file upload and linear scale - return nothing at all if they are left empty. (Other items will return `null` or "".) So how can I tell if that question has been answered or not?

For example, let's say I have a form of 4 scale items. If one of them is not answered, the item array will have 4 entries and the response array will have only 3. How would it be possible to know which item was left unanswered when you're looping through the items and responses? I'm stumped.

Here's the code I've got so far, which loops through form items and responses:

```
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var title = form.getTitle();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var responseSet = form.getResponses();
  var lastResponse = responseSet.length - 1;
  var itemResponse = responseSet[lastResponse].getItemResponses(); //this is the set of responses for the most recent submission

  var table = [];

  title = title + '\n';
  var docTitle = noteBody.appendParagraph(title);
  docTitle.setAttributes(titleStyle);
    
  var j = 0;
  for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    var itemType = items[i].getType();
    var itemTitle = items[i].getTitle();
    var thisResponse = "";

    //question items
    if (itemType != 'IMAGE' &&
        itemType != 'PAGE_BREAK' &&
        itemType != 'SECTION_HEADER' &&
        itemType != 'VIDEO'         )
      {

        //additional step needed for multiple answer options - turn array into string        
        if (itemType == 'CHECKBOX_GRID' || itemType == 'GRID'){
          
          table.push([itemTitle.toUpperCase()]); //add grid item title
          
          if (itemType == 'CHECKBOX_GRID') {var cgItem = items[i].asCheckboxGridItem()};
          if (itemType == 'GRID'){var cgItem = items[i].asGridItem();}

          var answerRow = [];
          var row = cgItem.getRows();
          var numRows = cgItem.getRows().length;

          //when question is unanswered
          if (itemResponse[j] == null){
            var tableRow = ["     [no response]"];
            table.push(tableRow);
          }
          else { //there is some response
            var cgResponse = itemResponse[j].getResponse();     
            for(n=0; n<numRows; n++){
              var rowTitle = "     " + row[n].toString();
              if (cgResponse[n] == null) {cgResponse[n] = "[no response]";} //when one row of a grid is left blank
              var answers = cgResponse[n].toString();
              answerRow = [rowTitle, answers];
              table.push(answerRow)
            }
          }
        }      

        else {
          
          //itemResponse[j] is the response to question #j (from the most recent answer set) 
          if (itemResponse[j] == null || itemResponse[j].getResponse() == ""){thisResponse = "[no response]";}
          else {thisResponse = itemResponse[j].getResponse();}
         
          var tableRow = [itemTitle, thisResponse]; 
            
          //turning response from array into string?
          var responseString = "";  
          for (m=1; m<tableRow.length; m++){
            responseString = responseString + tableRow[m];
            if (m<tableRow.length-1) {responseString = responseString + ", ";} //if it's the last one don't add this
          }
          tableRow = [itemTitle, responseString];
          table.push(tableRow);
        }
        
        j++;
      }
```

Comment: In the trigger handler for the onformSubmit trigger keep an object that tells you which questions must be answer.  Use the sheet name as the property and then e.range.getSheet() will tell which form is responding.

Comment: I am grateful for your response - unfortunately, I'm pretty beginner here. Could you possibly explain this to me a little further, or point me to somewhere that can do so? (I've been reading/watching videos on triggers but still not up to speed...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post some code that shows what you've attempted so far?

Comment: - [onFormSubmit(e) Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: When the user submits the form and the form submits the response to the linked spreadsheet it fires a trigger which calls a trigger handler that you have written and it loads the first parameter of the trigger handler with the event object.  Which has all of the answers and it also provides information about the line that was added too the sheet in the spreadsheet

Comment: `I am trying to iterate through a Google form and its responses ` Are you looking at the Form responses _after_ responses have closed. if so, you can ignore event objects. The linked spreadsheet will have a column for each question regardless of type., and a row for _every_ response, regardless of which questions were answered. So, if you loop through the Data Range, you can test for null and/or empty and substitute a meaningful answer (e.g. "Not Answered"). If you would like a more detailed response, please edit the question to include sample data and an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: I am adding code to the question that shows what I have so far. This loops through the form items and responses, but has the flaw I described. (Consider a form with 4 linear scale questions: if the user answers only 3 of them, it's impossible to tell from the response array which one was left out.) [Note that I am trying to accomplish this as script on the form, without using the spreadsheet, if it's possible.]

Comment: Ok, did some more learning and testing on this. If I use the onFormSubmit trigger, the event that is passed in still only contains filled answers (at least for a linear scale question). Still looking for a way to know if such a question was left unanswered (hopefully without needing to link the responses to a sheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to analyse the Responses for a Google Form and are concerned about how to deal with multiple linear scale questions where the respondent fails to answer one or more the question.

You want to do the analysis "from the form itself".

The following answer is adapted by combining the answers from two other questions:

- @Tanaike solved this problem in [Storing all forms answers in one single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69537071/1330560)
- @Matheus208 provided the method of converting unanswered questions to provide a more meaningful value in [Substitute value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47575480/1330560)

---

```
// based on so_69536568: Storing all forms answers in one single file
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/69537071/1330560
// by Tanaike
// h/t: Substitute value in array;
// h/t: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47575480/1330560
// by Matheus208

// function to be bound to the Google Form
function surveyAnalysis() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yryiSltp8zv6GJCkwFRl-qrftbK0dH64NtcDTbRadoU')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  // Gets the title and description of the form and write to spreadsheet
  var formTitle = form.getTitle()
  var formDesc = form.getDescription()
  sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(formTitle).setFontWeight("bold")
  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(formDesc).setFontWeight("bold")

  // get the question titles for Headers
  var headers = form.getItems().map(e => e.getTitle())
  // get the form Responses
  var formResponses = form.getResponses()

  // create an array of the responses for each question
  var values = formResponses.map(f => f.getItemResponses().reduce((o, i) => {
    var r = i.getResponse();
    return Object.assign(o, {[i.getItem().getTitle()]: Array.isArray(r) ? r.join(",") : r})
  }, {})).map(o => headers.map(t => o[t] || ""))
  // convert blanks answers to a meaningful text value
  var unansweredQns = "N/A"
  var adjustedValues = values.map(line => line.map(el => el.length === 0 ? unansweredQns : el))

  // paste the question headers to the spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange(3,1,1,headers.length).setValues([headers]).setFontWeight("bold").setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)

  // paste the adjusted question values to the spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(adjustedValues).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
}
```

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

---

Answer (score 1):

You want to analyse the Responses for a Google Form and are concerned about how to deal with multiple `linear scale` questions where the respondent fails to answer one or more the question.

It isn't necessary to separately interrogate form responses. The linked spreadsheet has a column for each question **regardless of type** and a row for every response **regardless of which questions are answered**. So one can loop through the data on the linked spreadsheet

---

```
function analyseResponses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetName = "Form Responses 1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var targetName = "Survey results"
  var target = ss.getSheetByName(targetName)

  // get the form description and title
  var formUrl = sheet.getFormUrl()
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  // Gets the title and description of the form
  var formTitle = form.getTitle();
  var formDesc = form.getDescription();
  target.getRange("B1").setValue(formTitle)
  target.getRange("B2").setValue(formDesc)

  // get the responses
  var responseRange= sheet.getDataRange()
  var responseValues = responseRange.getValues()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the response range = "+responseRange.getA1Notation())
  
  // add question headers to Target sheet
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,+lc-1) // ignore timestamp
  // Logger.log(headersRange.getA1Notation()) // DEBUG
  target.getRange(3,1,1,+lc-1).setValues(headersRange.getValues())
  
  // create a temporary array to hold survey results
  var targetArray = []

  //loop through the responses by row and column
  for (var i=1; i<responseValues.length;i++){
    // create temporary array to hold each row of survey results
    var rowArray = []
    for (var j=1;j<responseValues[0].length;j++){
      var cellRange = sheet.getRange(i+1,j+1)
      var cellValue = cellRange.getValue()

      // test if there was no response
      if (cellValue.length === 0){
        cellValue = "Not Answered"        
      }
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: Cell range = "+cellRange.getA1Notation()+", value = "+cellValue)

      // push item response onto rowArray
      rowArray.push(cellValue)

    }
    // push row Array onto targetArray
    targetArray.push(rowArray)

  }
  // Logger.log(targetArray) // DEBUG
  
  // update the target sheet with the survey results
  target.getRange(4,1,targetArray.length,+lc-1).setValues(targetArray)
}
```

---

**SAMPLE FORM: showing linear scale questions**

[image: form]

---

**SAMPLE - Spreadsheet Form Responses**

[image: spreadsheet]

---

**SAMPLE - Survey Report (BEFORE)**

[image: surveybefore]

---

**SAMPLE - Survey Report (After)**

[image: after]

Comment: Is there any way to do it from the form itself without going to the spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes. Refer to my second answer. In fact, your question is a duplicate of an answer developed by @Tanaike.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an easier way. Someone tell me if I messed this up?

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var items = form.getItems(); //includes non-question items
var responseSet = form.getResponses();
var lastResponse = responseSet.length - 1;

var allResponses = [];

  //get a list of all answers including null
  for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    if (responseSet[lastResponse].getResponseForItem(items[i]) != null){ //if not null, paste in the existing answer
      var answer = responseSet[lastResponse].getResponseForItem(items[i]).getResponse()
      allResponses.push(answer);
    }
    else {//if it's null, add a "" in there for the answer
      allResponses.push("");
    }
  } 

  for (a=0; a<allResponses.length; a++){
    console.log(allResponses[a])
  }
```

form:
[image: form]

results:
[image: results]

Comment: `an easier way` what does "easier" mean? `Someone tell me if I messed this up?` You have messed this up. If you are going to post an answer, then you ought to post some sample output. 1) this records only the most recent response and ignores all prior responses. 2) if the last question in the response is not answered by the respondent, then this script fails to recognise that question and the "non-answer. 3) the substitution of "a" for a non-answer fails because the "non-answer is not equal to "null". Have you tested this?

Comment: I apologize for not posting the answer well. You may have already discerned that I am new to stackoverflow and to programming. Trying to improve in both areas. This code is easier in that it's shorter and less complex. I have indeed tested this and it seems to work out well. I'm afraid I don't really understand your three points here. I'm happy to try to answer them if you care to explain them differently, but you certainly don't have to. I am grateful for everyone who has tried to help.

Comment: No worries. Create a form with sample questions and sample responses (include at least 4 linear scale questions:); you could use the results of the accepted answer as a guide. In particular, notice that the responses do NOT answer every question and neither "Ted" nor "Paul" answered the last (linear-scale) question. Now, run your script against that form. Do the results display ALL the responses, do they show ALL the answers to ALL the questions (including the non-answered questions)? Do non-answered questions show an "a"? Take a screen shot of the results and include the image in your answer.

Comment: This is a sample of ONE response. Do a few, mix up the non-answered questions, AND include a response where the respondent does NOT answer the last question.

Comment: Tested all kinds of permutations. Haven't found any that don't work. Hooray!